# Java multithreading scenario

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a Java class where I have a method that reads in thousands of product related records.Now for the same `ProductId`,I need to create a list of `products(product beans)` and send them to a method in a different class for Validation.To speed up the process.

I was think of spawning multiple threads - each thread responsible for sending each list of products for a product id to the `validate()` for validation.Also after validation,another method needs to be called in the calling class for further processing.I am aware of the Exceutor Framework in Java and have some information on it. The question is it feasible to design a multithreaded solution for this?Please advise.

**Example:**

```
Class A{
 List<Product> prodList;-- this prod List is populated with productBeans with same prodId.

Class B = new Class B();
B.validate(prodList);
processNextStep();
```

Can I spawn multiple threads that can validate each list of products?
`processNextStep()` this step needs to be processed after validate() has been finished.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tell me if I understood your question correctly. You have a large list of products, you populate another list with products from the large list and you need to validate the smaller list.

Comment: Thanks @bku_drytt.Actually what I tried to imply was that there are thousands of records - product related- that re being read.Now these records needed to be grouped according to Product-Id in a List and the list needs to be sent for validation.After validation,the next step needs to be performed.So in-order to hasten up the validation process of each groups,I was trying to implement using multi threading technique

Comment: Yes, multithreading sounds like a good idea for you in that scenario. You can simply split your records into independent containers (list) of your choice and have each thread perform validation on its associated container. So if your validation function takes an array parameter, just have every thread execute that function with their own record array.

Answer (score 0):

Executors offer an easy way to manage threads, but you will still have to write the code to execute the tasks and gather the results. One option that could be a good fit here is the [ForkJoin](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html) framework that was introduced in java 7. It's actually an implementation of ExecutorService.

Comment: Thanks @mvd.Will take a look.